# How ro access docker volume files from the code on docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i have creted a docker volume with such command

```
docker run -ti --rm -v TestVolume1:/testvolume1 ubuntu
```

then i created a file there, called TestFile.txt and added text to it

Also i have a simple "Hello world" .net core app with Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
COPY bin/Release/net6.0/publish/ ShareFileTestInstance1/
WORKDIR /ShareFileTestInstance1
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ShareFileTestInstance1.dll"]
```

I published it using

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

then ran

```
docker build -t counter-image -f Dockerfile .
```

And finally executed

```
docker run -it --rm --name=counter-container counter-image -v TestVolume1:/testvolume1 ubuntu
```

to run my app with a docker volume

So what i want to achive to access a file which is in a volume("TestFile.txt" in my case) from a code in the container.

for example

```
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists("WHAT FILE PATH HAS TO BE HERE") ? "File exists." : "File does not exist.");
```

Is it also possible to combine all this stuff in a Dockerfile? I want to add one more container next and connect to the volume to save data there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters for `docker run` can be either for docker or for the program running in the docker container. Parameters for docker go *before* the image name and parameters for the program in the container go *after* the image name.

The volume mapping is a parameter for docker, so it should go before the image name. So instead of

```
docker run -it --rm --name=counter-container counter-image -v TestVolume1:/testvolume1 ubuntu
```

you should do

```
docker run -it --rm --name=counter-container -v TestVolume1:/testvolume1 counter-image
```

When you do that, your file should be accessible for your program at `/testvolume1/TestFile.txt`.

It's not possible to do the mapping in the Dockerfile as you ask. Mappings may vary from docker host to docker host, so they need to be specified at run-time.